# Sql Server - Using a CTE combining values from multiple tables without joining

Tags: sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I've been using CTEs to build some specially formatted tables that I need, this has been working great as long as the data comes from one table or I can join, but now I am presented with a situation in which I don't have any common fields to join on.

Here is the Ideal end-result

```
+------+---------+
| p_id | value   | 
+------+---------+
| 1    | 1,55556 |
| 2    | 2,1212  |
| 3    | 2,6868  |
| 4    | 2,4545  |
| 5    | 1,55557 |
| 6    | 2,1212  |
| 7    | 2,6868  |
| 8    | 2,4545  |
+------+---------+
```

Here are some sample tables

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
 ([Emp_ID] varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
 ([Emp_ID])
VALUES
 (55556), 
 (55557)
;

CREATE TABLE Table2
 ([Type] Varchar(10), [Type_ID] varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO Table2
 ([Type], [Type_ID])
VALUES
 ('Black', '1212'),
 ('Red', '6868'),
 ('Orange', '4545')
;
```

Here is the CTE working with a single table

```
GO
WITH cte as (
    SELECT t1.[emp_id], C.Value
    FROM table1 t1
        outer apply (values
            ('1,' + t1.[emp_id])
       ) as C(Value)
)

SELECT
    row_number() over(order by [emp_id], value) as p_id,
    value
FROM cte
```

But what I want is something like this... Except when I do this i'm hit with "The multi-part identifier "t1.emp_id" could not be bound"

```
GO
WITH cte as (
    SELECT t1.[emp_id], C.Value
    FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
        outer apply (values
            ('1,' + t1.[emp_id]),
            ('2,' + t2.type_id)
       ) as C(Value)
)

SELECT
    row_number() over(order by [emp_id], value) as p_id,
    value
FROM cte
```

Now, I could do what I have done before, which is make a separate column for each value except this time I am dealing with hundred of values in table2 that I need to insert so that's not practical anymore.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can get the desired output. But I have the feeling I'm missing the point:

```
with cte as
(
  select '2,'+type_id as value, emp_id
  from table1 t1, table2 t2

  union all

  select '1,'+emp_id as value, emp_id
  from table1  
)
select value,
  row_number() over(order by emp_id, value) as p_id
from cte
```

Comment: This is it! I don't know that I could have conveyed what I am doing without writing paragraphs on end but this accomplishes exactly what I was trying to do, basically I am trying to output a text file that has the employee_id as the first item and then each of the 2, items define something on their profile which gets imported.  This helped a lot, thanks Tom!